# addHandlerAsync throwing an error when using pop-out on desktop

Tags: office-js, outlook-addin

I'm experiencing a problem with an Outlook Add-In I've developed for a MessageComposeCommandSurface extension point.

When the Add-In loads we call the following function:

```
  public async mapRecipientEventHandler() {
      await Office.context.mailbox.item.addHandlerAsync(Office.EventType.RecipientsChanged,
        this.recipientsChangedHandler.bind(this),
        null,
        null);
  }
```

This generally works fine but an issue occurs whenever we pin the Add-in then use the "pop-out" option on Outlook.

While the Popped-out items is working fine, we can see from some logging the following error being thrown for the initial instance of the Add-In:

> TypeError: Unable to get property 'addHandlerAsync' of undefined or null reference TypeError

So it looks like the initial instance of the Add-In is loading again which is odd as it no longer looks like a compose view but instead a read one.  I've tried retrying to get the mailbox item after a time delay to see if it could be a timing issue but even after waiting for 10 seconds before trying to get the mailbox item it still comes back as undefined.

Is anyone aware as to why this is happening?

Comment: Hey, we are trying to understand your scenario further. Can you tell us which client you're seeing this issue in (Outlook for Windows, OWA, Mac)? Are you executing the said code in the initial (pinned) add-in in Compose Mode, while a different (or same) add-in is running in a popout? If you could give us some clear reproduction steps, that would help us investigate this issue faster. Thanks.

Comment: Hey there, we're seeing this issue on Outlook for Windows.  The same Add-In is running in both the initial compose mode and the pop-out.  So we're basically going to a message entering compose mode on the email.  Then the Add-In opens as it is pinned and then we use the pop-out option for this compose message.

Comment: What build of Outlook are you using? Does your add-in support pinning and have you registered for the ItemChanged event? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/pinnable-taskpane#register-the-event-handler

Comment: I'm using build 12430.20184 of Outlook.  The Add-In does support pinning and we have also registered the ItemChanged event.

Comment: For this scenario, there should be an error message in the original taskpane and the item should be in read mode. Could you please list detailed repro steps for us to investigate? e.g. does the popup window come from an inline reply/forward?

Comment: If your add-in supports pinning, then I believe your add-in registers for the `ItemChanged` event. If that is accurate, then keep in mind that `Office.context.mailbox.item` can become `null` in certain scenarios, such as the one you described above. So the guidance is to perform a `null`-check before using `Office.context.mailbox.item`. This is documented here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/pinnable-taskpane. That might be the cause of the error you are experiencing.